# Windows Authentication Prompt - only some users

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-authentication

My intranet site has Windows Authentication enabled.
For me and a few other users, it works great, authentication happens in IE 'behind the scenes'.

But for some other (less privileged?) users (same domain), they receive a log-in prompt.
The computer settings/local intranet settings are the same.

When authentication is disabled, the page loads fine for everyone.
So that makes me think it's not a file permission issue.

What reasons could some users get authenticated and some not?

Comment: For this type of problem, the two most common culprits behind unexpected login prompts are (1) “Enable Integrated Windows Authentication” is unchecked under IE Tools > Advanced tab or (2) the intranet site is not listed under the “Local Intranet” zone (IE > Tools > Security tab > Local Intranet > Sites > Advanced). Did you check those two settings?  If neither of those are it, there is one more spot I can have you can check.

Comment: @T-Heron Thank you, I checked both, settings are same for the users who get the prompt and those who do not. If you don't mind I'd like to hear about the other spot!

Comment: For a problematic user, go to IE > Tools > Security tab > click Local Intranet > Custom level... button > scroll all the way to bottom and ensure that "Automatic logon only in Intranet zone is selected.

Comment: @T-Heron Again, thank you. The settings there are fine, same as the working users. I feel it must be some user permissions thing, I'll keep trying to hunt it down.

Comment: Compare the Active Directory group memberships between a  problematic user and someone who can get into the site successfully.  Somewhere in the differences may lie the answer to the problem.